# Sort rows based in ascending order using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works but checks only the first column. I want to check the 2nd column instead with the points. How do I alter it?

**HTML Table:**

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">School</th>
            <th width="20%">Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><h1>Event 1</h1></td>
          <td>School1</td>
          <td>74</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>School2</td>
           <td>69</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School3</td>
           <td>71</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School4</td>
           <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><h1>Event 2</h1></td>
          <td>School1</td>
          <td>34</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>School5</td>
           <td>29</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School3</td>
           <td>62</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School7</td>
           <td>15</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 var $tbody = $('#caltbl tbody');
            $tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
                var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                // if a < b return 1
                return tda > tdb ? 1
                       // else if a > b return -1
                       : tda < tdb ? -1
                       // else they are equal - return 0    
                       : 0;
            }).appendTo($tbody);
```

How do I got about this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vxa128L5/2/)

EDIT: I'm sorry guys but my live code is different with rowspan being used. Is there a possibility to have this in ascending order so that the events are sorted differently?

Comment: Change `:eq(0)` to `:eq(1)`? (The number is the zero-based index of the column...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the trs. Detach the td and insert to an array. Then append them back to each row

Add some class to simplify coding.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vxa128L5/4/)

HTML

```
 <table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">School</th>
            <th width="20%">Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="event1">
        <td rowspan="4"><h1>Event 1</h1></td>
          <td>School1</td>
          <td class="point">74</td>
      </tr>
       <tr class="event1">
          <td>School2</td>
           <td class="point">69</td>
       </tr>
      <tr class="event1">
          <td>School3</td>
           <td class="point">71</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="event1">
          <td>School4</td>
           <td class="point">11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><h1>Event 2</h1></td>
          <td>School1</td>
          <td>34</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>School5</td>
           <td>29</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School3</td>
           <td>62</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>School7</td>
           <td>15</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var $tbody = $(' tbody');
var array = [];
$tbody.find('.event1').sort(function (a, b) {
    var tda = $(a).find('.point').text();
    var tdb = $(b).find('.point').text();
    return tda - tdb;
}).each(function (idx, tr) {
  array.push($(tr).children('td').not('[rowspan]').detach());
});
$.each(array, function (idx, obj) {
    $(obj).appendTo($('.event1:eq(' + idx + ')'));
});
```

The JavaScript only applies to event1. You can simply modify it for arbitrary events.

---

Change the index as Mayank Pandey said. And..

Since your second column is number, you can just return their difference.

```
var $tbody = $('#caltbl tbody');
$tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
    var tda = parseInt($(a).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10); // always use the base number
    var tdb = parseInt($(b).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);
    return tda - tdb;
}).appendTo($tbody);
```

Comment: Even better :) however, my live code is different and isn't working. Could you help please. I want to do the sorting for different events like Event 1 to be sorted differently and Event 2 to be sorted differently. How do I go about making the changes? Check the updated JSFIDDLE

Comment: Thank you. However, I have over 50 such events and Copying and pasting for every event is far fetch! :( How can we solve this problem?

Comment: You can iterate over events. It can be achieved by simply using a for loop. I've updated the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vxa128L5/8/) for you. The point is to add appropriate event class and point class to the DOM.

Comment: Thank You so much! This is so awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

eq(0) means you are using the first index. Change it to eq(1) so that it can consider the second index.

```
var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text();
var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

Comment: Thank you. However, My live code is different and isn't working. Could you help? I want to sort for different events like Event 1 to be sorted differently and Event 2 to be sorted differently. Thank you so much. Check the updated JSFIDDLE